# Back button after form submit?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have looked everywhere and found nothing. I am not sure if it is possible, but I need a back button after a form has been posted in html. It is a hotel search and the client does not want the parameters set as GET. Does anyone have any idea how I can accomplish this in html, php, javascript or jquery? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Use the javascript `history.back()` command, tied to a button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most secure would be php,

`<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];?>">back</a>`

JavaScript can be disabled a times :)

Comment: hi this works, but I need to keep the form information that was submitted.. is there a way to do this using this? Thanks!

Comment: and you are NOT allowed to you GET correct? Well based on that, I suppose you could use `$_SESSION` to store the post data throughout the user's browsing session, however it depends on how much information you are storing.

Comment: I would be storing from 5 to 10 variables. It is a hotel search form, so they give the two dates they will go, # of adults, # of children, ages of children. So in the children variable is where it varies.

Comment: well on each page you need to access this data, there must be a `session_start()` function (before any HTML is echoed). then To set a session you would do `$_SESSION['whatever_you_want'] = "something"`. To call the session you would just treat it as a variable so `echo $_SESSION['whatever_you_want']`. Make sure, however that you have `session_start()` at the top of each PHP file or else it won't work.

Comment: thank you so much this works perfectly. If you would like to add it as answer so I can chose best answer!

Comment: Well you already marked my post as answer :) unless of course you are to start a new discussion and have me post my answer there.

Answer (score 1):

Just make the button change the location of the window to the location of the form.

Answer (score 1):

You should use : `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` in your page, or create a session.

Answer (score 1):

have you try this?

it brings you back to the previously loaded webpage.

```
<A HREF="javascript:javascript:history.go(-1)">Back</A>
```